# При програмном подключении к wifi на android 8.1 соединение держиться только 35 секунд

Tags: java, android, wifi

Пишу программное подключение к wifi устройству.Делаю через Broadcast Recessiver. Убил уже кучу времени в итоге добился стабильной работы на всех андроидах кроме 8. На 8 стандартный код не работает! Вот код самого подключения:

```
public void setWifiConnection1(View view){
 

     WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    
    
      WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    
      conf.SSID = "\"NETWORK_NAME\"";
      conf.preSharedKey = "\"PASSWORD\"";
                    int netId = wifi.addNetwork(conf);
                    if (netId == -1) {
                        netId = getExistingNetworkId(conf.SSID);
                    }
                            
                    wifi.enableNetwork(netId, true);
                    wifi.reconnect();

 }
        
   

private int getExistingNetworkId(String SSID) {
        
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        
            List<WifiConfiguration> configuredNetworks = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
            if (configuredNetworks != null) {
                for (WifiConfiguration existingConfig : configuredNetworks) {
                    if (existingConfig.SSID.equals(SSID)) {
                        return existingConfig.networkId;
                    }
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
```

Добавляю строчку wifi.disconnect(); Коннектиться только на 35 секунд.

```
                wifi.disconnect();
                wifi.enableNetwork(netId, true);
                wifi.reconnect();
```

[Вот весь код подключения с формой ввода](https://github.com/zoltanersek/android-wifi-activity)

Буду очень благодарен за любые советы и подсказки как добиться стабильной работы на 8-ке!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Восьмерка просто экономит батарею, если трафика никакого нету, то все логично. Можно сделать бесконечный поток, и в нем уже вызывать то, что необходимо, либо имплементься через `Runnable` и писать в `run()` то, что нужно для логики приложения